# EventTriggerBehavior doesn't work for AppBarButton

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, eventtrigger, appbar

I'm using EventTriggerBehavior in Blend and it doesn't work for AppBarButton in test application for windows phone 8.1 when i'm using ElementName binding. The same EventTriggerBehavior for Button works fine.

```
 <Grid x:Name="grid">       
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>                   
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=okButton}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                <core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                </core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>                    
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="okButton"  Icon="Accept" Label="appbarbutton">                                        
        </AppBarButton>       
        <AppBarButton x:Name="cancelButton" Icon="Cancel" Label="appbarbutton"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

This behavior is working fine. okButton is collapsed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNIWt.png

```
 <Grid x:Name="grid">       
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">       
</Button>
</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="okButton"  Icon="Accept" Label="appbarbutton">                                        
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>                   
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                        <core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    </core:ChangePropertyAction>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>                    
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </AppBarButton>       
        <AppBarButton x:Name="cancelButton" Icon="Cancel" Label="appbarbutton"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

button is still visible. Behavior doesn't working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVQC7.png

Comment: Probably the binding to element name is failing. Try using a command that you can invoke via click event handler or something like that...

Comment: No, binding is fine. I was using Expression Blend and choose TargetObject in UI. CallMethotAction and other Behaviors still doesn't working. It seems that ElementName binding doesn't working for Page elements. I've checked it for other AppBarButton inside BottomAppBar and it works fine.